# Rearrangement of a surface equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry

The following equation is for equipotential surfaces when $\psi$ is constant, where $0<\psi<\pi$ and $a$ is a constant:

$$ (x^{2}+y^{2})\cos^{2}\psi+z^{2}\cot^{2}\psi=a^{2} $$

How can we express $\psi$ in terms of $x,y,z$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $c=\cos{\psi}$. The equation is
$$ (x^2+y^2)c^2 + z^2 \frac{c^2}{1-c^2} = a^2, $$
since $\cot{t}=\cos{t} / \sin{t}$, and rearranging this gives
$$ (x^2+y^2)c^4-(x^2+y^2+z^2+a^2)c^2 + a^2 = 0, $$
which is a quadratic equation for $c^2$. Solve this for $c^2$, take the square root, and then use $\psi=\arccos{c}$, which is well-defined given the range in which $\psi$ lies.